# Get entity metadata in form extension Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, entity, metadata

I try to get entity metadata, when I do this:

```
$entityMetadata = $this->validator->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor('Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Post');
```

All works fine, but when I do this:

```
$entityMetadata = $this->validator->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor($formData);
```

`$formData` equal to  `string 'Acme\DemoBundle\Entity\Post' (length=27)`

I got error:

```
Cannot create metadata for non-objects. Got: NULL
```

What I am doing wrong? Can somebody help me? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the getMetadataFor signature ( http://www.doctrine-project.org/api/orm/2.3/class-Doctrine.ORM.Mapping.ClassMetadataFactory.html ) You have to pass a string. Maybe you should try something like:

```
$entityMetadata = $this->validator->getMetadataFactory()->getMetadataFor(get_class($formData));
```